# Where to check battery state and set CPU governor/performance level during boot?

Tags: ubuntu, startup

My laptop supports setting a "performance level" (normal, overclock or silent) that influences the CPU clock rate and fan speed beyond the usual CPU governor setting.

The level is set to "normal" by default, but I would like to automatically set it to "silent" when my laptop boots without the charger connected. (Reacting to ACPI events after the system has booted would be nice, but isn't a priority right now.)

Writing a script to check the power state and set the performance level won't be too difficult, but where and when during the boot process should I run it?

<sub>I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.</sub>

Comment: @sgmart Thanks, but that isn't the main point I'm asking about. I'd really like advice on what would be the most sensible place to put the script that does that. Should it be an `init.d` script? In `/etc/profile` or the Xsession config? Or somewhere else entirely?

Comment: @sgmart Debian-like systems have `/etc/rc{0..6,S}.d/` directories with symlinks to scripts in `/etc/init.d` to execute them at the appropriate runlevel, so that might actually be a good place to put the "battery state → performance level" script.

Comment: Only Ubuntu I have at hand is an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  This actually has an `/etc/rc.local` script that should be run at boot.  You might try putting a call to your script there (I don't know whether this would work on 14.04, since AFAIK Ubuntu is in a rather fragile state concerning its `init`-system, but it should be worth a try, at least since major Linux distributions tend to put much afford in backwards-compatibility).

Comment: Did you tried `laptop-mode-tools`?

Comment: @delta24 I saw `laptop-mode-tools` in a similar question on here, but according to its website, it doesn't seem to be customizable to set the performance level instead of the CPU governor.

Comment: If it doesn't work for you, there are many others. Refer [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling).